# Best practice to throttle concurrent calls

Tags: c#, asp.net, synchronization

I need advice on the best practice for throttling calls to code within an asp.net MVC web application. We have a class that handles some complex work involving calling out to Salesforce, let's call it `ComplexSfLogic.cs`.

Salesforce has a limit of 10 concurrent requests at a time, and given the complexity of our logic and high number of users, we are pushing up against this limit.

`lock()` can be used to limit access to a resource ala 1 at a time, but I want to limit access to 10 at a time - essentially throttling the calls to my class when more than 10 happen concurrently.

I can think of lots of ways to handle this by [coding up a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429414/is-there-a-better-way-to-throttle-a-high-throughput-job), but is there a best practice or existing .net class that can throttle method calls like I'm describing. I think my biggest problem is that I'm not using the right keywords when searching for an answer so I'd appreciate any direction.

I've seen [`ServiceThrottlingBehavior`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicethrottlingbehavior.aspx) class for throttling WFC calls directly, but I need the throttling to happen at my `ComplexSfLogic.cs` class because that class will make multiple calls in some instances and they need to be grouped together. Thanks!

Comment: `SemaphoreSlim` with initial count 10 ?

Comment: This looks like a design issue... first of all using a SemaphoreSlim  works only within a single process and the regular Semaphore works only within a single machine, so this solution is completely non-scalable. you probably need throttling on the server and error handling on the client. or a better solution would be some sort of queuing mechanism, maybe using MSMQ or RabitMQ for communication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `SemaphoreSlim`. It allows to to set a limit on the number of threads being in the critical section. It also supports async which can be a good idea if many threads might be waiting and queueing up.

You can also use this as a load breaker and fail the operaiton if you fail to acquire the semaphore after x milliseconds (or immediately).